# A dynamically added button makes post back to login page

Tags: vb.net, onclicklistener, buttonclick

In order to Add dynamically a Button I use the following code inside the `LoginButton_Click` sub

```
Dim ModeratorButton As New Button
AddHandler ModeratorButton.Click, 
AddressOf Me.ModeratorButton_Click
With ModeratorButton
 .ID = "ModeratorButton"
 .Attributes("OnClientClick") = "ModeratorButton_Click"
 .CssClass = "ModeratorButton"
 .Text = "Ενημέρωση"
End With
MessagesPanel.Controls.Add(ModeratorButton)
```

I also have a protected sub in order to handle the event

```
 Private Sub ModeratorButton_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

End Sub
```

As a result of all these I receive the normal page 
 
With the Panel I want and the controls I need in it. 
The issue starts when I push the `ModeratorButton` and the code never goes to the `protected sub` I mention earlier
Instead of that it makes a post back to the `LoginPage`

Is someone to assist me on this?

Comment: What are the statements under the `ModeratorButton_Click` event. And in the `AddHandler` , use `AddHandler ModeratorButton.Click, AddressOf ModeratorButton_Click`

Comment: @preciousbetine With the AddHandler I'm adding the event handler for the button.click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After postback you need to AddHandler again.

For example, like this.

```
Private Sub _Default_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Request.Form("LoginButton") IsNot Nothing Or
       Request.Form("ModeratorButton") IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim ModeratorButton As New Button
        With ModeratorButton
            .ID = "ModeratorButton"
            .Attributes("OnClientClick") = "ModeratorButton_Click"
            .CssClass = "ModeratorButton"
            .Text = "Ενημέρωση"
        End With
        AddHandler ModeratorButton.Click, AddressOf Me.ModeratorButton_Click
        MessagesPanel.Controls.Add(ModeratorButton)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub ModeratorButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

End Sub
```

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/317794/how-to-dynamically-create-controls-in-asp-net-by-using-visual-c-net

> Note When you create dynamic controls on a Web Form, the controls must be created and added to the controls collection either in the OnInit or in the Page_Load events. Otherwise, the controls behave unexpectedly.

Comment: @m.mukai Yes... that was the solution. Call them on th `page_Load` sub and raise them when ever you want.... yes that's it Thank you very much